# Passing parameters to a promise chain

Tags: javascript

I'm having some problems with passing parameters through a promise chain I set up. Here's a basic example of what I'm trying to do.

```
var dummyReq = { client: null };
var dummyUser = { email: 'user@secretdomain.com', password: 'admin' };

function printEmail(request, user) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log('Email:', user.email);
        return resolve(request, user);
    });
}

function printPassword(request, user) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log('Password:', user.password); // <-- user is undefined
        return resolve(request, user);
    });
}

printEmail(dummyReq, dummyUser)
    .then(printPassword)
    .catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Unexepected error has occured');
});
```

In the second promise the parameter user is undefined, how can I pass multiple parameters through a promise chain, as these promises continue more information gets added to the chain, by the end of it I'm passing 5 values through to the last promise.

Should I just use ES6 operators to combine them into an object and deconstruct them on every call? for example `return resolve({request, user})` and then `const { request, user } = param`

Comment: yes, you're right, `resolve` and `reject` should receive one parameter.

Comment: Can't you simply use `.then(request => printPassword(request, dummyUser))`?

Comment: Notice that you shouldn't use promises at all when you are only synchronously resolving with a value.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, I'm aware, Just wanted a very simple example.

Comment: @Phil Yes, but that breaks the chain. For example, if I wanted to do `.pirintEmail(...).then(printPassword).then(updateDatabaseValues).then(..)` and have `.catch` handle the `reject()` for all of these.

Comment: @Hobbyist no, it doesn't break the chain, the arrow function returns the promise just the original callback function would.

Comment: @Bergi My bad. Completely forgot that the arrow function returns the result of a single statement call.

Comment: @Hobbyist: *Concise*-form arrow functions return the result of the single *expression* they contain implicitly, yes. Note that it has to be an expression. Verbose-form ones (with `{}`) don't.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are on the right track. Promise objects hold a single fulfilled value which is passed to onfulfilled reaction handlers. A non promise value, or the fulfilled value of a a promise when it eventually becomes fulfilled, is used to fulfill the next promise in a chain of promises. If you want to propagate multiple values to the next promise handler you have to use a single object value to do so.

So let's assume that `printEmail` and `printPassword` actually do something asynchronous rather than the synchronous operations in the post.

printEmail becomes:

```
function printEmail(request, user) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log('Email:', user.email);
        resolve( {request, user} );
    });
}
```

without a "return" statement inside the executor of the new Promise - 
the return value of an executor function is not used and will generally be  `undefined`.

printPassword becomes

```
function printPassword(data) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log('Password:', data.user.password);
        resolve(data);
    });
}}
```

Whether you deconstruct a data object into  variables or not is a stylistic rather than technical question. Similarly whether you pass the same object down to multiple handlers in a chain of promises, deleting or adding properties if required, or create a new object with only the properties needed in following steps is entirely a matter of choice and style.

Comment: What does "{request, user}" mean? It looks like an object literal that is missing its keywords. Is this valid JavaScript syntax?

Comment: @DavidSpector `{request, user}` uses [short hand property notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015}) introduced in ECMAScript 2015 (i.e. ES6), and is a short way of writing `{request: request, user: user}`.